# <PHP> How to rename all the pictures on a folder to it's timestamp. MM-DD-YY hh:mm:ss

Tags: php, timestamp, rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of folders with pictures on server, the file names are random and a lot, but every file is a jpg. I need to rename every file on any given folder to the information on the timestamp.

Example. 
File names 1.jpg , 2.jpg

After convention 12/15/11 10:20:58.jpg , 12/15/11 11:21:50.jpg .

The actual Date format is not important.

P.S. Important that it only modifies the jpg files and not the folder names nor sub-folder content.

Thanks.

Comment: your problem is solve or still searching for some logic.....

Comment: Yes i'm still searching. Your answer works but i need it on a bulk scale, the folders contain more than 1000 files each. I am curretly trying out Robbo's answer, and am getting an error. I will kip trying, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/directoryiterator).

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('path/to/files');
foreach ($dir AS $file)
{
    if ($file->isDot() OR $file->isDir() OR $file->getExtension() != 'jpg')
    {
        continue;
    }

    // This is just doing it to a timestamp, wrap filemtime in data() to format the name how you like
    rename($file->getPathname(), $file->getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . filmtime($file->getPathname()) . '.jpg');

}
```

This is from memory so there might be some issues but I am fairly sure that is what you wanted.

Comment: also be careful, test this first.. we don't want you losing everything somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/capadron/public_html/testsite/test.php on line 11".I am trying to find a solution for this error, bu thanks this was exactly what i was locking for.

Comment: I did corrected the filmtime( to filemtime(, but get the same error.

Comment: Yesyou are right. It was something on the server.i had it restarted and it is working find now. Thanks for the big help.

Comment: should select this as your answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$req_file="newname.png";//required file
echo $file_name=strtotime(date("m-d-Y H:i:s"));//convert time to string 
$new_filename=$file_name.".png";//creating new file name

$path="C:\\wamp\\www\\practice\\";//path provides
rename("C:\\wamp\\www\\practice\\newname.png", "C:\\wamp\\www\\practice\\".$new_filename);//rename of file
#rename($path.$req_file, $path.$new_filename);//another way of rename of file

convert file name into string stamp like 1344664010.png
```